# Can you manually set the version number in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, version, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to set the version number of a PWA (Progressive Web Application) in the `manifest.json` or `service-worker.js` file to override the default (`1`) to a custom number?

---

I've already tried adding a `version` key in `manifest.json`, but the version number stayed at `1`.

```json
{
  "version": 2
}
```

I've also tried to add a `version` variable in `service-worker.js`, like so. However, that didn't set the version correctly either.

```js
const version = 2;

// Also tried...
const VERSION = 2;
```

---

So, is it possible to set the version number in a PWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `id` field was added to the [Web App Manifest spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#id-member) in late 2021. Chrome implemented it in [version 96](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6064014410907648).

I don't think anyone else has implemented this yet, but I believe you can get a similar effect with query parameters in the `start_url`.

[Here's an article that explains further.](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/pwa-manifest-id/)

Comment: I've seen you answer when it was released, but I didn't understand how to implement it. Can you please elaborate further in your post? Thanks for helping!

Comment: We need to clarify that article. Basically, add an `id` member to the top level of your web app manistest. (That's the same level as the `start_url`. It can take any string you want. When you want to release a new version of your PWA, change the id.

Is there anything specifically that's confusing you?

Comment: No, thanks, I get it now! Thanks for helping!